# Blackberry alarm integeration

Tags: java, blackberry

here is my app.
i have triggered the alarm but how i can set alarm for specific date. please tell me.
  public class Alarm 
    {

```
private Event event;
public void myAlarm(String name,String bankName,String AccNo)
{
    try
    {

        EventList eventList = (EventList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.WRITE_ONLY);
        event = eventList.createEvent();
        event.addString(event.SUMMARY, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, name+"\n"+AccNo);
        event.addString(event.LOCATION, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, bankName);
        event.addInt(event.ALARM, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, 0);
        event.addDate(event.START, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE,System.currentTimeMillis()+120000);
        event.addDate(event.END, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, System.currentTimeMillis()+360000);
        event.commit();


    }//end of try block
    catch(Exception e){}


}//end of method myAlarm

}//end of main class Alarm
```

Comment: Indent your code with four spaces to have it formatted properly, and remove the redundant blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RepeatRule recurring = new RepeatRule();
recurring.setInt(RepeatRule.FREQUENCY, RepeatRule.YEARLY);
recurring.setInt(RepeatRule.MONTH_IN_YEAR, RepeatRule.MARCH);
recurring.setInt(RepeatRule.DAY_IN_MONTH, 11);
recurring.setInt(RepearRule.COUNT, 1);
event.setRepeat(recurring);
```

This will fire the alarm for only one time in: March, 11th.

Is this what you need ?